# Fade last previous element back in after fading out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got tabs with content but I'm a bit confused as to which jQuery I need. What I want to achieve is:

- click to fade in article / hide tab content
- click to fade out article / show tab content

(I want to be able to either click 'close' or click the next tab to remove the article and fade back in tab content).

I'm not sure what to use.
`.hide()` is hiding everything so I can't get the tab content back in.

Tried hiding, fading and using the current class but no luck!

Can't find a similar question either but if there is, please provide a link also so I can see if I can match up to mine.

Thanks for any help.

My example here:

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});

$('.open-article').click(function() {
    $('.article').show();
    $('.tab-content').hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.article').hide();
});
```

```css
.section {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.article { 
    background: green;
    width: 40%;
    display: none;
}

ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
    background: #ccc;
}

.tab-link {
 background: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.tab-content {
 display: none;
 background: #ccc;
}

.tabs .tab-link.current {
 background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content.current {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="first">
        <a href="#tab-1">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="sec">
        <a href="#tab-2">Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="first" class="tab-content current">
    <p class="open-article">one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sec" class="tab-content">
    <p class="open-article">two</p>
  </div>
</section>

<article class="article">
  <p class="close">close</p>
  <p>As I move away from the article (either pressing close or the next tab), I want the last active tab to fade back in but with 'close' all I get is hiding everything and clicking the next tab doesn't work.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgdZdm what is the problem exactly?

Comment: When you press the content in the tab. At the minute it's just an example p tag saying "one" and "two".

Comment: @gauravmuk  When I fade out the article nothing else is faded back in.

Comment: @gauravmuk Because I've got .hide I'm not sure what to use to fade back in the previous content on click or on tab change

Comment: what is nothing else? when i click on one, i can see one and when i click on two, i can see two. i m not able to understand the problem

Comment: @gauravmuk The tabs work fine. Click a tab and then the content (ie the p tag that says 'one') it will open the article but if I try changing tab then the article won't hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZgVmK

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');

    $('.article').hide();

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    $('.tab-content.current').show();
});
```

The problem is you need to show the content back.

The last line is the answer to the problem. You need to show back the current tab's div back again.

Comment: `parent().parent().parent()`? Are you sure? What if some DOM element gets inserted? You can easily avoid this by using `parents()` or `closest()`.

Comment: it's the OP's code, the first motive is to solve the problem with minimal code regression. i haven't changed the mentioned line.

Comment: Thats the whole point of stack overflow. To optimize and correct the user. Don't follow the user. If something is incorrect, fix it and share the knowledge.

Comment: my motive was to solve his problem first, optimization comes after i have solved the problem. anyways, that is not the problem we are solving right now as to how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```js
$('ul.tabs li').on('click', function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');

  $('.tab-content')
    .hide() // first just hide all 
    .removeClass('current'); // and remove the class current

  $('#' + tab_id)
    .show() // show the tab 
    .addClass('current'); // add class current to it        
});

$('.open-article').on('click', function() {
  $('.article').show();
  $('.tab-content').hide();
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $('.article').hide();
  $('.tab-content.current').show(); // add this line
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.article {
  background: green;
  width: 40%;
  display: none;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-link {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tabs .tab-link.current {
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="first">
        <a href="#tab-1">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="sec">
        <a href="#tab-2">Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="first" class="tab-content current">
    <p class="open-article">one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sec" class="tab-content">
    <p class="open-article">two</p>
  </div>
</section>

<article class="article">
  <p class="close">close</p>
  <p>As I move away from the article (either pressing close or the next tab), I want the last active tab to fade back in but with 'close' all I get is hiding everything and clicking the next tab doesn't work.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code, according to your requirement:

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');
  $('.article').hide();
  $('ul.tabs li, .tab-content').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').hide();
  $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current').show();
});

$('.open-article').click(function() {
  $('.article').show();
  $('.tab-content').hide();
  $(".current").removeClass('current');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.article').hide();
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.article {
  background: green;
  width: 40%;
  display: none;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-link {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tabs .tab-link.current {
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="first">
        <a href="#tab-1">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="sec">
        <a href="#tab-2">Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="first" class="tab-content current">
    <p class="open-article">one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sec" class="tab-content">
    <p class="open-article">two</p>
  </div>
</section>

<article class="article">
  <p class="close">close</p>
  <p>As I move away from the article (either pressing close or the next tab), I want the last active tab to fade back in but with 'close' all I get is hiding everything and clicking the next tab doesn't work.</p>
</article>
```